# No response output from php and Axios Node Js

Tags: php, node.js, express

I want to send value from Node Express to php in server. The php script has a calculation then php should return the result back to Node Express.

But php script does not return any values. The following console echos `Undefined`

```
console.log(response.data.Final);  // Undefined
console.log(response.Final);        // Undefined
console.log(response.data.result);  // Undefined
```

**console output of Node Js**

```
Connected successfully to the database
{ status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers:
   { date: 'Wed, 10 Oct 2018 14:28:19 GMT',
     server: 'Apache',
     'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.2.10',
     'access-control-allow-headers': 'node-request, node-response, node-request, node-response',
     'access-control-allow-methods': 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
     'access-control-expose-headers': 'node-request, node-response, node-request, node-response',
     'access-control-allow-origin': '*, *',
     'content-length': '0',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' },
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 2 },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php',
     data: '{}' },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'mytestpage.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 221,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 132,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 604 },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'mytestpage.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 221,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 132,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 604 },
     _header: 'POST /calculate/index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\nHost: mytestpage.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/calculate/index.php',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php',
        redirects: [],
        read: [Function] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 2,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php' },
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      { accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  data: '' }
```

**php script**

```
<?php
    if(isset($POST['takeFromNode']))
    {

    $num1 = 10;
    $num2 = $POST['takeFromNode'];          // getting from Node Js

    $result = ($num1 + $num2);     // This result should be return

    print(json_encode(['Final' => $result]));  // Code to return back
    exit();

    }    
?>
```

**Node script**

```
var axios = require('axios')

route.post("/calculate", function (req, res, next)
{
  axios.post('http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php', {takeFromNode: takeFromNode})
  .then(response => {
    if(response)
    {
      console.log(response);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error));
})
```

Comment: It should be `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

Comment: No success again also `undefined`

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers development tools and see what the actual request looks like, what data it posts and what it returns. Regarding the PHP, the above mentioned type is the only issue as far as I can see.

Comment: I check this using Postman, because of `POST` request.

Comment: What do  you mean "because of POST request"? That can be viewed in the network tab as well. If you change `$POST` to `$_POST`, post to `http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php` with the form param `takeFromNode` set to some value with postman, what is the response?

Comment: Also, where do you set the value `takeFromNode` in your JS before trying to use it in the request to your php-file?

Comment: As you said I changed to `$_POST`. Then The browser only supports for `GET` request. No `POST` request by using browser. Anyway I give value using postman and checked the network tab, it shows status `200`.

Comment: I am giving the value for `takeFromNode` using   `var takeFromNode = req.body.takeFromNode;`

Comment: Ok. Let's start from the beginning. In postman, when you make a post request to the index.php using postman (and added `takeFromNode` param to the request body with some value using formData or x-www-form-urlencoded), pressing "send", you should get some response in Postman under the response "body" (still in postman). What do you get? There is no "network tab" in postman. Doing that will test the PHP file without invoking any node or anything. If that still doesn't work, then you're either not doing exactly as I just mentioned or your code doesn't look like you say.

Comment: The postman still loading not stop. Node prints `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think the problem in php script. I does not response as valid JSON. Should I declare before any `array` or anything in php script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7011366/simon-paris) said, Axios using [JSON](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

Change the following

```
  axios.post('http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php', {takeFromNode: takeFromNode})
```

to

```
  axios.post('http://mytestpage.com/calculate/index.php',require('querystring').stringify({takeFromNode: takeFromNode}))
```

will work fine.